# How to change position of text on imageview in android studio?

Tags: java, android, xml, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am making a quote posting app using java and firebase as the storage cloud. In the app user will write quote first and then after clicking on compose button new activity will be started where user is allowed to choose picture from gallery , after picking the picture he/she will be able to see the image beneath the text and should be allowed to change the position, size, color and style of text within the image.

here is the screenshot of the activities.
I have used edit text in create quote activity then imageview and textview in compose activity where imageview is beneath textview.

[Create quote](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccx3C.png)

[compose](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nD9FO.png)

[Pic from gallery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHlpj.png)

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://github.com/SarthakDoshi04/text-on-image.git) is a library that can help you to add text and move around the image. when coming to changing the font style. create a new button/dropdown to select the style and set theme.

Hope this helps. Feel free to ask for any clarifications.